# How to pass value or param from jsp to Spring controller?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm trying access some value from my jsp file in Spring controller. All examples that I've found was with `<input>` or `<form>` code, but I want to pass "clear" value (just String), for example `<c:set var="name" value="Ololo"/>`or smth like this and print it in Conroller.

Comment: You might want to add a bit more context to your question. What have you tried already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Data can flow only in one direction, from controller to view (jsp). If you have to send information back to the controller then you should make http request. That's the reason you only see `<form>` and `<input>` in examples

Comment: so, how can we make a http request for this purpose?