# How to pass text field value from a jsp to spring controller class and vice versa

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, spring-mvc

How can we get jsp data (i.e. a textarea input) in a java class (i.e. spring controller with a function which return a `ModelAndView` object)?

We have spring controller so we could not use servlet and thus we do not want to get values in `doGet`, `doPost`.

I have read this [How to pass value or param from jsp to Spring controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38468408/how-to-pass-value-or-param-from-jsp-to-spring-controller) post; however, it does not provide any simple sample or helpful links.

Comment: Hello Aquin,Hope my answer helped you .If yes please accept the answer if not please let me know so that I can improvise on that and help you to give  a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
@RequestMapping(value="/url you are hitting",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView
FitchService(@ModelAttribute Bean/Model cmd,BindingResult
result,ModelMap model) {

    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView(displayURL);
    //here displayURL is where you want to forward which is a string i.e jsp return  modelAndView 
    return modelAndView;
}
```

then get them in the jsp like:

```
> <c:out value="${value you want to fetch}" />

If you want to pass parameters from jsp then you can use @RequestParam annotation also.
```

http://jeromejaglale.com/doc/java/spring/mvc

```
Please refer above link
```

Comment: and what about from jsp to spring controller?

Comment: If you want to pass parameters from jsp then you can use @RequestParam annotation .

Comment: You have bean attribute r8 .You can access using getters and setters.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out, if you are asking for something like this -

https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-textbox-example/

Answer (score 0):

You can construct spring form and bind a model

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>

    <form:form method="post" modelAttribute="userForm" action="/userActionUrl">
        <form:input path="name" type="text" /> <!-- bind to user.name-->
        <form:errors path="name" />
    </form:form>
```

then in controller you receive the data populated

```
@Controller
public class UserController{

@RequestMapping(value = "/userActionUrl", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveOrUpdateUser(@ModelAttribute("userForm") User user,
        BindingResult result, Model model) {
    user.getName()
}


}

public class User {


    // form:input - textbox
    String name;

   //getter setters

}
```